# Não consigo alinhar um form a direita

Tags: html, css

```
 <form class="red">
   <h1></h1>
 </form>

   <div class="map">
     <center>
       <img class= "imgmap" src="https://data.whicdn.com/images/134220427/large.jpg" alt="Forestvile" width="600px" height="500px"/>
     </center>
   </div>

<form class="yellow">
  <h1></h1>
</form>
```

Estilo

```
.yellow{
    align-self: flex-end;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -500px;
    background: rgba(255, 251, 0, 0.534);
    justify-content: end;
    align-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    align-self: flex-end;
    text-align: end;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: O que seria "alinhar um form a direita"?

Comment: duas coisas, primeiro, `text-align: end;`não alinha a direita, segundo é melhor por o conteúdo num `div` por exemplo. O `form` não é uma tag de formatação, o propósito é agrupar campos de formulário

Answer (score 1):

Escola da Vida, tudo bem?

Você terá que criar uma DIV para servir de grid container com as seguinte declarações CSS:

```
/* Assim declarando, todos os elementos filhos diretos 
daquele container se transformam em grid items.  */
display: grid; 


/* Definindo quantas colunas seu grid ira possuir. */
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

Segue um guia muito bom sobre [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

Observações:

Nessa linha

```
 <div class="map">
 <center><img class= "imgmap" src="https://data.whicdn.com/images/134220427/large.jpg" alt="Forestvile" width="600px" height="500px"/></center>
 </div>
```

A tag HTML `<center>` [Esta obsoleta](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp), defina o posicionamento dos seus elementos com css.

Tenta não definir o tamanho das imagens utilizando `width` ou `height` na tag `img`. 
A recomendação da [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp) e de que se use o atributos `style` para definir tamanho delas. Isso impede que outras folhas de estilo do projeto interfiram no tamanho delas.

```css
form {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.container-formularios {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
}

.map {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.map .imgmap {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.yellow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(255, 251, 0, 0.534);
  position: relative;
}

.red {
  width: 100%;
  height:150px;
  background: rgb(233, 111, 80);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-formularios">
  <form class="red">
    <h1></h1>
  </form>

  <div class="map">
    <img class="imgmap" src="https://data.whicdn.com/images/134220427/large.jpg" alt="Forestvile" />

  </div>

  <form class="yellow">
    <h1></h1>
  </form>

</div>
```

Restou alguma dúvida? Espero ter ajudado, abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Você está a usar o `text-align` errado. Tem de usar `text-align: right;` ou então `float:right;`

Veja [Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp) a documentação do `text-align` e [Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) a documentação do `float`

Answer (score 0):

Olá, @Escola da Vida,

Utilize a propriedade float:right, e pode estar faltando também o display para que o elemento fique atribuído ao contexto do envoltório, ficando assim:

```
.yellow{
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
}
```

- Dessa forma,você terá o bloco inteiro do formulario posicionado ao lado direito.
- Se oq vc quer não é isso, e sim que o conteúdo do formulário seja alinhado a direita, como o texto do label, os campos e o botão, então pode fazer assim:

.yellow{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:right;
}

```
.yellow h1,
.yellow label,
.yellow input,
.yellow textarea,
.yellow button{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: isso vai alinhar "o form" à direita e não seu conteúdo, será que é isso que ele quer? pra mim ficou meio confuso pra ser sincero :)